# Vue Dynamic URL From state. In axios call

Tags: api, vue.js, dynamic, axios

I want to parse the axios url call from a variable state in vuex. As simple as this:-

```
state: {
getOrganizationURL: "opensource",
}

actions: {
  getOrganizationDashboard({commit, state}) {
      axios
      .get(`"https://xxx/api/report/"${state.getOrganizationURL}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${state.currentAuthToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        commit("setOrganizationsDashboardData",response.data)
        
      }); 
  },
}
```

when checking the network on the browser. The API call is going to a weird url instead.
e.g

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/%22https://xxxx/api/report/%22opensource
which leads to page not found...

I think it a minor mistake. Any tips please?

Comment: why do you have backticks and double quotes in the string? I'm thinking that's the problem, to write interpolated strings in js you only need backticks

Comment: True. You are right. Now it's working. Thanks alott